# Add [ajaxcontroltoolkit] as a synonym of [ajaxtoolkit]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Could [ajaxtoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxtoolkit) be made a synonym of [ajaxcontroltoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxcontroltoolkit)?

It looks like they share the initial part of their tag wikis, with [ajaxcontroltoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxcontroltoolkit) having additional detail while [ajaxtoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxtoolkit) does not. Note that [ajaxcontroltoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxcontroltoolkit) is also more popular.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer simply to bump this. These do indeed appear to be dupes (I just discovered them after reviewing [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2806094) which tagged a question already tagged with [ajaxtoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxtoolkit) with the more popular [ajaxcontroltoolkit](/questions/tagged/ajaxcontroltoolkit).)

Unfortunately, it's not a technology I've ever worked in or answered questions about, so I can't even suggest the tag synonym; a mod or somebody who happens to see this question and has sufficient rep in the tag will have to do it.

Comment: I edited said comment and agree it should be done, with ajaxcontroltoolkit being the preferred tag.